# How do I obtain a property descriptor inside of a class proxy handler using JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, reflection

With a class proxy I would like to interrogate the property descriptor before performing a particular action; do one thing if it's an accessor, do something else if it's a method, and a third thing if it's a property. The problem though is that I don't think I'm looking at the correct owner of the feature:

```js
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T

const handler: ProxyHandler<any> = {
    get(target, propertyKey, receiver) {
        const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, propertyKey)
        console.log(desc) // undefined

        return Reflect.get(target, propertyKey, receiver)
    }
}

function Adapted<U extends Constructor<any> = Constructor<any>>(Base: U = Object as any) {
    return class extends Base {
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args)

            return new Proxy(this, handler)
        }
    }
}

class Foo extends Adapted() {
    method() { return "foo" }
}

new Foo().method() // "foo"
```

Do I have to walk the prototype chain until I find the correct owner? Is it something simpler?

Comment: So by using Object.getPrototypeOf(target) I can obtain the descriptor for methods and accessors, but property interception still seems out of reach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evaluating the immediate prototype seems sufficient. Having to walk up the prototype chain is thankfully not required:

```js
const handler: ProxyHandler<any> = {
    get(target, propertyKey, receiver) {
        const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(target), propertyKey)

        // do something based on desc type

        return Reflect.get(target, propertyKey, receiver)
    }
}
```

I don't think there is a practical means of intercepting instance properties from the super class so I've given up on that. For my specific use case it's sufficient to prevent public properties from being defined in the first place via `Object.freeze`:

```js
function Adapted<U extends Constructor<any> = Constructor<any>>(Base: U = Object as any) {
    return class extends Base {
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args)

            return Object.freeze(new Proxy(this, handler))
        }
    }
}
```

Which still allows practical usage:

```js
class Foo extends Adapted() {
    #prop: string
    constructor(prop: string) {
        super()
        this.#prop = prop
    }

    get prop(): string {
        return this.#prop
    }
    set prop(value: string) {
        this.#prop = value
    }

    method() { return "method" }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    method2(){ return "method2" }
}

let foo = new Foo("prop1"),
    bar = new Bar("prop2");

console.log(foo.prop) // prop1
console.log(bar.prop) // prop2

bar.prop = "12"

console.log(bar.prop) // "12"
```